# Auto click input from other page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Hy for example if on page Y (not my website) page contents next button :

```
<input class="xxx" type="submit" id="xxx_play" value="Play">
```

And i want with the help of php or jquery to autopress this input after x Seconds is this possible ?

Comment: No, it's not possible. You can't use JavaScript on *your* page to click a button on some other site's page. If this were a regular web form, I'd suggested using PHP to POST directly to the server, but the example you've given seems to indicate you want to push a button which triggers some other script in the page to play something. This can't be done. Script served by your server to your page cannot interact with script served by another server on another page.

Comment: if you have no access to source code how are you planning to do this?

Comment: Yes you can, it is called userscript. Though you won't click the submit, you can submit the form.

Comment: i know the source code but i want only this button to play

Comment: If you want do to it from your another webpage, it's against [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Anyway, this could be done if you put JavaScript code to adressbar, console or userscript.